# How To Distract Clients From Using IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

How can we distract our clients from using IE6. We know IE6 is not a good standard-compliant browsers; has many issues. How to satisfy clients so that they do not use IE6?

Thanks...

Comment: EDIT: i believe this should be a chained process; you persuade the client not to use IE6, client in turn persuade people they are concerned with. So we should be able to satisfy the clients; this is very important; there should be some solid reasons so that clients say yes with what we say. Looking for better solutions/answers. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm currently in the process of building a new site for my company and I've been looking at [http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ie6-upgrade-warning).

Essentially it's a little javascript lib that checks  to see if the user is running IE6 and if so it displays a nice little overlay on top of your site. The only problem I've got with it is that it completely blocks the user from using your site. I'd like to allow for them to use it anyways but I'd like them to know that their experience may not be as good as it could be. I'm sure it can be adapted though, ***you should never exclude people from using your site based on their user agent***. That being said I think it's a good tradeoff that you try to get your users to upgrade and if they don't wan't to they can still use your site but they probably won't see all of the fancy pancy browser tricks that you can do with modern browsers.

[image: IE6 upgrade warning]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://ie6-upgrade-warning.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/example.png))</sub>

It sure looks nice anyway

Other resources include http://ie6update.com/ (not a fan though, you shouldn't trick users)

**Update**: Seems like someone made a bit more customizable version of this written in jQuery. See [jreject.turnwheel.com](http://manlius-ner.com/zcvisitor/b7769a57-9195-11eb-8f0e-127e266ebe63/72092e88-2c53-401c-b988-51ef43ce1034?campaignid=b16698b0-0d5e-11eb-8341-0a52992aaad9)

Answer (score 7):

One of the reasons this problem exists is as follows.

Many IE6 user have no choice. They sit behind corporate firewalls with locked down machines and while on their home machines they will have the latest technology they are constrained by the workplace rules and policies.

So why do the corporates not upgrade from IE6 to 7 or 8? Well here is one reason. Workload.

As a sysop you need to upgrade 500 machines to the new browser.

In many cases these browsers run mission critical add-ins as ActiveX's etc so to do the upgrade you have to do all the testing and verification and then do a planned roll out upgrade, which will have problems, hiccups and glitches, a lot of work and late nights and unpaid overtime and a lot of flak from the users as you do this.

And what is the payback for this upgrade? Well the internal systems work on IE8 exactly as they worked on IE6, (well not always and you may need to rewrite that as well) but the users can now access the latest startup site that plugs into Facebook (but will be gone in 6 months) perfectly but it is not work related.

So unless there is a tangible business benefit many shops simply cannot se a reason, or justify the cost of a browser upgrade.

These locations will convert, when they go to Windows 7 perhaps or because the "application" they use internally is upgraded and needs the newer browser version. But at this point there is a justification for doing it.

N.B. I have recently worked in two jobs where IE6 compatibility was a must for this reason, large client bases, behind firewalls with lockdown, and i am not stating the above as a reason/excuse not to do it. The sooner the better.

Comment: Good answer (even if an older question - still relevant). I've run into issues with corporate environments in IE6 several times, and it's 2011 now!

Answer (score 4):

Provided they have the proper permissions to do install software on their machines, use [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/intl/en/chrome/chromeframe/). The speed boost, if nothing else, should be incentive alone.

Comment: To quote from the Chrome Frame homepage: **"Note: This is an early-stage release, intended for developers and testing."** That really doesn't sound like something you should recommend to a customer...

Comment: Still, is better than IE6 in terms of security and whatnot. The results are more reliable. And, you know how google likes to keep things in beta forever...

Comment: Many companies will flat-out refuse to use anything in beta. It's important in corporate-world to have official support available.

Comment: So is IE6 still supported, then?
I think that what will deter companies form using chrome-frame is not that it hasn't been released as a final yet, but rather that they don't want to alienate users by forcing them to stop using IE6. But then again, chrome-frame does allow your users to keep using IE6 if they so want. If they're open minded enough to have it installed, it will be used, if not, nothing more than a non-modal message with an invitation will appear.

Answer (score 4):

"The customer is always right."

You can advise them otherwise, but if they want IE6 for whatever reason then it's up to them.

Comment: Customer is the most important person - does not make them right.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is by educating them, make them aware of why you are blocking IE6. Do a comparison, case study, etc to convince them, try and put it in terms they may understand, try to convince them that using IE6 is a bad idea (whatever your reasons).

Its simple to implement a script to prevent IE Browsers from connecting to your site, however doing that may result in users being turned away. If this is a public site take into consideration the market share internet explorer has, unless your site is really incredible it is unlikely you will get a user to install a new browser.

To get around this in the past a simple splash page that informes them of the reasons not to use IE6, Example:

***You are currently using internet explorer, while you may continue to browse this site using IE, please be aware that some functionality may not be available due to compliance standards within internet explorer, and due to this we do not support issues that arise when using Internet Explorer. We recommend using Google Chrome (Download here) or Mozilla Firefox (Download here).***

If this is within a corprate environment you can always work with the IT department to ensure that alternate browsers are distributed. I recommend Google Chrome, simply beacuse of the ability to create "Application Windows" that eliminate problmem causing elements of the browser GUI (Back buttion etc...)

Comment: So because IE6 is out of date, you want to stop them using ALL versions of IE? Or did I mis-read? It's a big flaw to hate all IE flavours.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago there was a collective effort in Norway to get users away from IE6. Several of the largest sites in Norway participated, and the user got a kind warning on top of the site that recommended him to upgrade or switch browser for an improved browsing experience - if using IE6.

Check out what [Wired](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2009/02/norwegian-websi/) said about it!

Comment: this is great to know; such efforts should take place globally

Answer (score 1):

Having a site that *elegantly degrades* when the user's browser is IE6 is the best option. IE6 users should still be able to use your web site - if a particular feature requires a modern browser a user will be more likely to switch if they already find your site useful.

Another point: modern javascript libraries like jQuery makes it easier to code sites that are compatible with IE6.  There's no need to turn away potential customers because of their web browser choice. If you're a web designer it's your job to make sure they have a good experience.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this comes down to the reasons you want them to stop using IE6. IE6/7 are a pain in the bum if you let them be. We're now taking a more aggressive approach to browser adoption when it comes to what you can/can't do.

For instance, when you visit our new sites in most browsers you'll get rounded corners, transparency, gradients etc. When you visit in IE6 you get a square, opaque, monotone website. Wherever you have PNGs you'll get a simple GIF (even if it looks pants).

Unfortunately IE6 is tied to many businesses for internal reasons (using apps etc) and you can't force them to upgrade but you can give them a subtle message.

Comment: i wonder why not all browsers follow the same css, html specification

Answer (score 1):

make them understand that ie is  not bad, its ie 6 thats bad .. if they wish to use ie they can surely use it but could use ie 7 ir even ie 8... make them see that how ie 7 and 8 provide some great features which are not there in ie 6..
also ie 8 is the only browser that follows strict css 2.1 methodology
plus there are many websites which previously were running in ie 6 (with no problem) are running under a warning message that some context may not be suported by ie 6 for eg. www.yahoo.com, so why to use it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in one of our projects. I made a simple conditional check and displayed an additional div with links to download firefox, Chrome and IE-8.
Try facebook.com on IE-6. This was my inspiration for the additional div.

Comment: yeah i know that about facebook and no doubt that is what we can do in the end i think. thanks

Comment: do tell me if you find any other alternative, will be a good addition to my knowledge. Facebook way for me was the simplest for both user and as a developer. It would take hardly couple of hours to get working. One issue we faced initially was distinguishing IE6 from IE7 and IE8 so just have that in mind while you are coding rest would go smooth.

Answer (score 1):

In line with Markus' post, it's simple enough to display a popup when the site loads with a warning. Ideally you won't show this every time they load a page of course, that will get old fast.

You have a good opportunity when working on a spec with your client, to tell them "it will cost $X more if we have to support older browsers including IE6 (don't *just* say IE6), and it will mean we can't easily add more advanced functionality... supporting older browsers will detract from the overall quality and increase time & cost.

Answer (score 0):

make a whitepaper

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Charge extra -- double or treble rates or more -- to support IE6. (even IE7 these days).
2. Point out that IE6 (and WinXP too) will be losing the last vestiges of support in the near future. If you think they're insecure now, just wait till that happens -- no more security fixes. If you're still developing for IE6 now, then you're clearly not going to be ready for the upgrade in time, so you *will* be hacked, and hacked badly. If your client is willing to accept that, then that's his problem, but you need to help him understand the gravity of the problem. He needs to be putting his upgrade plans in now, not getting more dev work done for the old systems.